# Не работает псевдокласс :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Не работает hover.
Посмотрите пожалуйста.

```css
.mother{
    margin: 54px 74px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.logo{
        margin: 30px 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.menu li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
.menu li{
    width: 180px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.logo :hover + .menu li{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> new project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mother">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лишний пробел оставили в этой строке: `.logo:hover + .menu li{` -> `.logo: hover + .menu li{`

```css
.mother{
    margin: 54px 74px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.logo{
        margin: 30px 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.menu li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
.menu li{
    width: 180px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.logo:hover + .menu li{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> new project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mother">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Все получилось!!! Большое вам Спасибо за оперативный ответ! а то намучался я уже)

Comment: @ArtashesMuradyan Галочка слева - щёлк! :)

Answer (score 1):

Если между селекторами стоит пробел - это означает "элемент соответствующий селектору, находящийся в элементе соответствующем предыдущему селектору" т.е. у вас указано "при наведении на элемент в элементе с классом .logo". Если коротко - то просто удалите пробел между .logo и :hover

Answer (score 0):

псевдокласс hover не является родителем элементов, грубо говор вы просто поставили пробел

```css
.mother{
    margin: 54px 74px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.logo{
        margin: 30px 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.menu li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
.menu li{
    width: 180px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.logo:hover + .menu li{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> new project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mother">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Кажется уловил)